# How does the AccountData type work in FRAME runtimes?

Tags: frame, balances, accountdata

The [FRAME system for runtime development](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/frame/) defines an [`AccountData` type](https://crates.parity.io/frame_system/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.AccountData), which is coupled with [data from the Balances Pallet](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_balances/struct.AccountData.html) in [the Polkadot runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/v0.9.16/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L221).

1. What other types of data could be tracked using this type?
2. Why doesn't the Balances Pallet track its metadata "natively" as opposed to coupling with the FRAME System `AccountData` type?

Answer (score 5):

I believe I'd asked a similar question on stackoverflow a while ago and it may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70845959/balances-accountstore-definition-in-substrate-runtime

Specifically this paragraph:

> Storing account balances in the system pallet also maintains some other frame_system information that may be important to keep around for a certain runtime configuration. But having consumers, providers and sufficients inside a runtime with multiple pallets and potentially interacting with other runtimes becomes quite crucial.

Answer (score 1):

1. The FRAME System `AccountData` type could track any data structure that implements `Member + FullCodec + Clone + Default + TypeInfo + MaxEncodedLen` (which we know by looking at what `AccountData` is bound by [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8423d2f59e53bf178d3462b28ddd7152d83de17e/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L325-L327)).

   The [`AccountData`
   type](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_balances/struct.AccountData.html)
   from the Balances pallet satisfies this requirement. And in this
   context, this type is just a struct that holds account information.
2. The Balances pallet could be configured to use storage native to its own instance, so long as it satisfies the [`AccountStore`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_balances/pallet/trait.Config.html#associatedtype.AccountStore) type it's configuration expects. This type is the Balance pallet's concept for "*a location to store information about accounts using me*". Because under the hood this type expects a [`StoredMap`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/trait.StoredMap.html), any type that implements `StoredMap` can be used here.

   The reason the Balances pallet is typically set to use the `System`
   pallet (which has an [implementation for `StoredMap`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#impl-StoredMap%3C%3CT+as+Config%3E::AccountId,+%3CT+as+Config%3E::AccountData%3E-for-Pallet%3CT%3E)) is because `AccountData` from the Balances pallet is most commonly used
   alongside other data the System pallet keeps track of (such as `nonce`,
   `consumers`, `providers` and `sufficients`).

   This may sound more intuitive if you look into the `system.account` storage item of any Substrate chain built with FRAME:

   ```
    {
     nonce: 0
     consumers: 0
     providers: 0
     sufficients: 0
     data: {     // < - this is taken from `AccountData`
       free: 0
       reserved: 0
       miscFrozen: 0
       feeFrozen: 0
     }
   }
   ```